# Auto authenticate HTTP authentication

Tags: php, authentication

Is there any way, in php, to submit (automatically) the user and pass to an HTTP authentication popup? The HTTP authentication isn't my script, so I have no way of controlling it myself, but I'd like to just be able to pass the authentication information automatically rather than having to enter the login manually. Possibly via a curl function or otherwise. Or, even if I need to go lower level for this, like c++ or command/bash script, that would also be okay.

Comment: You could try `https://<username>:<password>@url.com` format?

Comment: Haha so simple. Yeah that worked. If you post as an answer I can check you as best answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a username and password in the URL directly.

`https://<username>:<password>@url.com`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Examples

Answer (score 0):

You can implement basic auth pretty easily.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Comment: I saw that, while searching. Which showed how to handle my OWN authentication, unless I was missing something, but not how to auto-submit an answer to another server's authentication. Is this what you meant? I wanted to make sure I was clear enough in my post.

Comment: No, basic auth wouldn't be good for your situation. You could use curl with the basic auth url format mentioned in the question comment, check that you don't get a http 401 error, and then store the username in a cookie but even that requires collection of use and pass on your site. What security is the other site using? Oath is designed for this scenario